# Cannot Modify Header Warning

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the following warning output from my site:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/doc/www.xxx.com/www/themes/Divi/includes/builder/functions.php:1) in /www/doc/www.xxx.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1195.
```

first line in functions.php is

line 1195 is:

```
$location = wp_sanitize_redirect($location);

if ( !$is_IIS && PHP_SAPI != 'cgi-fcgi' )
    status_header($status); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups

    **header("Location: $location", true, $status);**

    return true;
}
endif;

"header("Location: $location", true, $status);"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Also the last line of your code makes no sense. Should this be echoed out? Also Using double quotes within double quotes is asking for trouble.